# Django AssertionError at /play/api/5/play/ The `request` argument must be instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `myApp.views.TrackPlayAPIToggle`

Tags: django

I am trying to implement an api version of a play button on a django website.

This is how far I got:

models.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
plays       = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,related_name='track_plays')


def get_play_url(self):
    return "/play/{}/play".format(self.pk)


def get_api_like_url(self):
    return "/play/{}/play-api-toggle".format(self.pk)
```

---

views.py

```
class TrackPlayToggle(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get("id")
        obj = get_object_or_404(Note,id=id)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.plays.all():
                obj.plays.add(user)
            else:
                obj.plays.add(user)
        return url_


from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import authentication,permissions
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

class TrackPlayAPIToggle(RedirectView):

    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    @api_view(['GET', 'POST', ])
    def get(self,request,format=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Note,id=id)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        updated = False
        played = False
        if user.is_authenticated():
            if user in obj.plays.all():
                played = True
                obj.plays.add(user)
            else:
                played = True
                obj.plays.add(user)
                played = False
            updated = True
        data = {
            "updated":updated,
            "played":played
        }
        return Response(data)
```

---

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/play/', TrackPlayToggle.as_view(), name='play-toggle'), 
url(r'^api/(?P<id>\d+)/play/', TrackPlayAPIToggle.as_view(), name='play-api-toggle'),
```

---

Ive added the API Decorator, because without it, I get a TypeError:

```
get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'
```

and when I try to add id=None I get an AssertionError:

```
.accepted_renderer not set on Response
```

Is this because I used id instead of slug?

---

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you thought adding the `@api_view` decorator would solve your TypeError. That decorator is for function-based views; it has no use in class-based views, where you define which methods are supported by simply defining the relevant methods. Remove the decorator.

The way to solve the original problem is to add the `id` parameter to the method; and the way to solve the problem with the renderer is to inherit from the correct parent class, which should clearly not be RedirectView.

```
class TrackPlayAPIToggle(GenericAPIView):

    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        ...
```